# How to work with 16 GB orthophoto raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, gdal, image-mosaic

I would like to use one GeoTIFF raster in a custom ArcGIS-Engine Application, but my provider gave me 4 orthophotos GeoTIFF 4 GB each, because GeoTIFF is limited to 4 GB.

Is there any other way to mosaic these images in a format (lossless and well supported), for example, as in file geodatabase or Postgres SDE database (using Arcgis tools or open source tools both are welcomed) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of ArcGIS by utilizing a [Mosaic Dataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_mosaic_dataset/009t00000037000000/) with an optional Raster Catalog - I believe both require ArcGIS for Desktop Standard or Advanced license levels.

There are some [tools to help manage your rasters in a Mosaic Dataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exploring_mosaic_datasets_and_raster_catalogs_in_ArcCatalog/009t00000030000000/), besides mosaicing them, it also lets you choose coordinate system/projection, build overviews, choose compression, blending type (colour balance), and others.

There are also options related to "serving" the rasters in a server environment like setting download limits (set to 0 for download restricted).

You can start by creating an empty geodatabase and then using ArcCatalog, right click the empty geodatabase and navigate to **New** > **Mosaic Dataset** to start the raster import and setup.